# con not invoke "" because this."" is null (or) Cannot invoke "CustomerRepository.findAll()" because "this.customerRepository" is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When we get error syaing that - can not invoke "" because this."" is, how to resolve this?

For e.g.,
Cannot invoke "com.saran.sprndatajpa.config.CustomerRepository.findAll()" because "this.customerRepository" is null

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error occur as the required bean is not autowired.

In this case, if we autowire customerRepository, the error will resolve.

```
 @Autowired
 CustomerRepository customerRepository ;
```

Thanks.